# How to build a qt project from command line?

Tags: windows, qt, compilation, qt-creator, qmake

I've seen similar questions, but they all address slightly different situations than my own.

I have the source code for a qt project on a github repo, including the .pro file.  Basically, I want to know if it's possible for someone on a Windows machine to clone the repo and build the executable from the source code without downloading and configuring Qt Creator.  If it is possible, what prerequisites need to be met, and what steps need to be taken in order to build the project?  The project uses qmake and not cmake, which probably affects the answer.

Comment: execute `qmake` :-)

Answer (score 5):

Install Qt. Download and install [Git](https://gitforwindows.org/) for Windows. In Git Bash, go to a folder you want to use for a project. Execute the command `git clone`. Run `Start -> Qt<version> -> Qt Command Prompt`. CD to this directory and execute:

```
qmake <your_project.pro>
mingw32-make
```

or if you are using `MSVC`, commands should be

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
qmake <your_project.pro>
nmake
```